# Why does wireless adapter work (though slowly) even if the driver is not working properly

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers

I have set of follow up question from my previous question: 
https://superuser.com/questions/896294/wi-fi-is-slow-only-on-acer-laptop-but-works-great-on-android-mobile-and-ipad.

So my questions are:

1. Why does the wireless adapter work at slow speeds, if the driver is not OK?
2. What is the use of the wireless virtual adapter?
3. How is it that a Windows 7 x64 driver works on a Windows 8.1 OS?

Comment: What is the adapter you are using? It could be that the adapter is actually a slower speed compared to that in your other devices.

Answer (score 0):

1. The 'broken' driver might be mis-identifying or mis-configuring the wireless chipset. Or it might be making incorrect assumptions about the environment, either the hardware (the rest of the machine), the OS or even the country the  machine is in. It could also be mis-reading the returns from the WiFi and working in a 'slow and safe' mode because it "hear's" interference. With WiFI it's even possible that one driver will prefer the old and very busy 2.4GHz but another will be happy using the (much 'cleaner') 5GHz spectrum.
2. It allows you to create multiple logical adaptors when you have one physical adaptor. That way properties like the IP address, the network you're connected to and so forth may be different on the different 'virtual' adaptors. (You'll need to look at the documentation, or even experiment, to see exactly what you can change)
3. They are two different versions of the same operating system. Microsoft try very hard to make sure that older software continues to work on newer versions of the OS, this includes third party drivers. The differences between Version 7 and Version 8.1 are mostly in the 'skin' that the OS shows the user. There are very few (possibly None) differences at the driver level.

For your specific WiFi issue I would *guess* that the Windows update version of the driver is 'more generic' in some way. A conspiracy theory might say, though it's impossible to prove, that the drivers for the older chips have been slowed down to make the new ones look better. But I would never suggest that could be true.